# Find source image from azw3 file

Tags: kindle, mobi, azw

When looking at the rawml of a azw3 file using kindle unpack. Most image embeds look something like this. (This is the rawml of an epub converted to azw3.)

```
<img src="kindle:embed:0003?mime=image/jpeg" class="c8" alt="gloriainexelcisdeo"/><br class="calibre"/>
```

Is it possible to find the actual source image from this in the unpacked book folder using this information.

In the mobi7 format, you just do a pattern match to the content.opf to get the file location of the image.

How do you do that for azw3?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not programmer. You can be used free soft Calibre and plugin KindleUnpack to understand the internal structure of the azw3 format. Or delve into the principle of the original Python script, what and how it does.